# High-resolution square product images on product list pages

Tags: image, product-list, product-images

I'm trying to show square product images on the product list pages, where images for hundreds of products range in dimensions.

When I use [this](http://2ammedia.co.uk/web-development-blog/magento-adaptive-resize-resize-to-best-fit/) adaptive resize

```
<img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId();" 
src="<?php echo $this
->helper('catalog/image')
->init($_product, 'small_image')
->constrainOnly(FALSE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->adaptiveResize(300,300); ?>" width="300" height="300"
```

it shows squares but the image quality is bad. When I set `constrainOnly(TRUE)`, the quality is good, but the squares have some black in them to fill the rest of the square that the image doesn't fill.

How can I get as high as possible image resolution whilst also squaring the images (ideally showing the centre of the image)? Is there any alternative method?

(I tried [this](https://github.com/obukhow/AdaptiveResize) adaptive resize too)

**Update**

I accepted the solution below however I was still left with bad resolution on images. Because I am working with images of different dimensions, some landscape, some portrait, the best solution for me was to manually crop the images into squares (in gimp, change the relative scale so the smallest side is equal to the size of the image I need whilst retaining aspect ratio, then change canvas size). All the solutions I've seen don't work well on images like these.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922287/magento-how-to-remove-black-image-from-image-backgrounds

Comment: You did not say what adaptiveresize function you used. You did not post any demo images to show the problem. And you expect help. Enjoy waiting!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `resize(width, height)` with `constrainOnly(TRUE)`.

Try this:

```
<img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" 
src="<?php echo $this
->helper('catalog/image')
->init($_product, 'small_image')
->constrainOnly(TRUE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize(300,300); ?>" width="300" height="300"/>
```

Reference: [link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-resize-image/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use this the images are not squared.

Comment: It should work, I have tested it. Please check each line thoroughly.

Comment: thanks, I found that I was using some css to set `width:100%` and `height:auto`. So now I have squares, but the resolution is still not ideal. Thanks for your answer.